# Text output from a SSH connection to a Mikrotik appliance cannot be properly read by bash?

Tags: bash

I'm writing a simple script to notify me whenever a new firmware update is available in my Mikrotik router. The RouterOS command for this purpose is:

```
ssh myrouter system package update print
```

And when its run normally it works fine, showing something like this:

```
            channel: stable
  installed-version: 6.48
     latest-version: 6.48.1
             status: New version is available
```

The full command I am using to only retrieve the relevant info so a notification is triggered is:

```
ssh -q myrouter system package update print |tail -2 |head -1 |sed "s/: /\n/" |tail -1
```

Which results in this when it is run "as is" (not inside a script nor anything else):

```
New version is available
```

However, I cannot seem to be able to parse this text inside a simple `if` statement, no matter if I manipulate it directly or first redirecting it to a local file:

```
UPDATES_AVAILABLE=$(ssh myrouter system package update print |tail -2 |head -1 |cut -d: -f2)

if [[ "$(echo ${UPDATES_AVAILABLE})" == "New version is available" ]]; then
  echo "INFO: New firmware version is available"
fi
```

This last one always returns no content, wether is run inside a script or directly in the shell.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh nevermind, I just fixed it.

After redirecting the output to a `/tmp/mikrotik.tmp` file I just thought about running:

```
file /tmp/mikrotik.tmp
```

And then I saw that it returned this:

```
mikrotik: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

So as soon as I added `| dos2unix` inside my string filter command it just started working as expected, and now this:

```
UPDATES_AVAILABLE=$(ssh myrouter system package update print |dos2unix |tail -2 |head -1 |cut -d: -f2)

if [[ "$(echo ${UPDATES_AVAILABLE})" == "New version is available" ]]; then
  echo "INFO: New firmware version is available"
fi
```

Is returning correctly:

```
INFO: New firmware version is available
```